# api call returns 405 invalid http status ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am doing http get request in my app and my api is deployed in my profile domain ( app.pankajpant.me/api/users ), i have cors enabled in my domain.

below is the request from postman 
[image: Rest Api Result]

Below is the Header result from Postman
[image: Header from Postman]

This is the error i am getting in console.
[image: Error]

Below is the code i am trying :

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.http.get(url, {headers: this.header})
            .subscribe(res => {
              console.log(res);
              resolve(res.json());
            }, (err) => {
              console.log(err);
              reject(err);
            });
        });
```

Please Help me.

Comment: well, there seems to be some issue with your cors settings? Or then you could try and enable cors in your browser as well. here is extension for chrome (if you do not already have it): https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: Thanks AJT_82, i will try and let you know